# Confusion in RegExp Reluctant quantifier? Java

Tags: java, regex

Why do I get the output `ab` for the following regular-expression code with a Relucutant quantifier?

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc*?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("abcfoo");
    while(m.find())
      System.out.println(m.group()); // ab
```

Similarly, why do I get empty indices for the following code?

```
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?");
   Matcher m = p.matcher("abcfoo");
   while(m.find())
     System.out.println(m.group());
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In addition to Konrad Rudolph's answer:

```
abc*?
```

matches `"ab"` in any case and `"c"` only if it *must*. Since nothing follows the `*?`, the regex engine stops immediately. If you had:

```
abc*?f
```

then it would match `"abcf"` be cause the `"c"` must match in order to allow the `"f"` to match, too. The other expression:

```
.*?
```

matches nothing because this pattern is 100% optional.

```
.*?f
```

would match `"abcf"` again.

Answer (score 5):

`*?` matches zero or more matches, but *as few as possible* (and by the way, that’s usually called “non-greedy”, not “reluctant”). So if zero matches is possible, that’s the optimal match.

What exactly do you want to achieve? Maybe non-greedy matching isn’t what you need.

Comment: Java does call it "reluctant". http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: I think "reluctant" is the best word for them, although "non-greedy" is good too.  But "lazy" (the other most common descriptor) is misleading IMO; they actually work harder than either greedy or possessive quantifiers.

Comment: @Alan Moore: I agree, “lazy” usually is something else in CS (see lazy evaluation).

Answer (score 2):

It never makes sense to have a reluctant quantifier as the last thing in a regex.  A reluctant quantifier matches only as much as it has to in order to achieve an overall match.  That means there has to be something *after* the quantifier to force it to keep matching.

If it seems odd to have something that can be put such a pointless use, it's probably because reluctant quantifiers are an add-on--something that's not possible with "real" regular expressions.  Some other examples of pointless usage are the "quantifier" `{1}`, and `\b+` or any other zero-width assertion (`^`, `$`, lookarounds, etc.) with a quantifier.  Some flavors treat the latter as a syntax error; Java allows it, but of course only applies the assertion once.

Answer (score 2):

The `?` reluctant quantifier makes `.*` match as few characters as possible, only matching more character if it's required by backtracking.

Here's an illustrative example of using regex to find a non-empty prefix that is also a suffix of a string (no overlapping).

The capturing group `\1` in the first pattern is greedy: it first matches everything, and takes as less as it backtracks. As such, the pattern will find the longest possible prefix/suffix match:

```
    System.out.println(
        "abracadabra".replaceAll("^(.+).*\\1$", "($1)")
    ); // prints "(abra)"
```

Now `\1` in the second pattern is reluctant; it first matches nothing, and takes more as it backtracks. As such, the pattern will find the shortest prefix/suffix match:

```
    System.out.println(
        "abracadabra".replaceAll("^(.+?).*\\1$", "($1)")
    ); // prints "(a)"
```

In your case, the `.*?` can match an empty string, and never needed to backtrack and match more since it was enough for the overall pattern to match.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html)

---

Here's another illustrative example of reluctant quantifier on a finite repetition:

Here, `x{3,5}` is greedy, and will take as much as possible.

```
    System.out.println(
        "xxxxxxx".replaceAll("x{3,5}", "Y")
    ); // prints "Yxx"
```

Here, `x{3,5}?` is reluctant, and will take as few as possible.

```
    System.out.println(
        "xxxxxxx".replaceAll("x{3,5}?", "Y")
    ); // prints "YYx"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     *?-> also call it as Lasy star
        ^abc*?f
    *?----> repeats  0 or more times
    ^---> regular expression for start of the string
      Example:  abcf00abcf00 --->Matches:"abcf"00abcf00
In this case c must select to reach f

        abc*? 
    *?----> repeats 0 or more times 
    Matches ab
      Example:  abcabcabcabc -----> Matches:"ab"c"ab"c"ab"c"ab"c

        abc.* matches any character except line break
       Example: abcabababbababab --->Matches:"abcabababbababab"

        ab.*?
      example:  ababababbababab ---> "ab""ab""ab""ab""ab""ab""ab""ab"
    abc? matsches ab or abc
```